# Error: "Cannot find 'get' method for string class."

Tags: string, matlab, class, methods

I'm coding with GUIDE. I want to get data input from `handles.edit1`,...`handles.edit8` and save to variable `handles.in(1,1)`,...`handles.in(1,8)`. My code is below and I get an error:

> Cannot find 'get' method for string class.

```
edit = ["handles.edit1","handles.edit2","handles.edit3","hanles.edit4","handles.edit5","handles.edit6","handles.edit7","handles.edit8"]
for i = 1:1:8
    handles.in(1,i) = str2num(get(edit(1,i),'string'));
end
```

Comment: I cannot follow your code or your problem, nor can I reproduce your it. You better have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

you should change

```
edit = ["handles.edit1","handles.edit2","handles.edit3","hanles.edit4","handles.edit5","handles.edit6","handles.edit7","handles.edit8"]
```

to

```
edit = [handles.edit1,handles.edit2,handles.edit3,hanles.edit4,handles.edit5,handles.edit6,handles.edit7,handles.edit8];
```